# Temporizador 5 segundos Python

Tags: python

tengo una consulta de programación de Python.

Me gustaría realizar una aplicación, que cuando se me detecte una condición, me muestre un mensaje a los 5 segundos de darse esa condición. Si antes de 5 segundos se pierde esa condición, no lo muestra. Se puede decir que en funcionamiento es un temporizador de retardo a la conexión

Esa condición de la que hablo, es que una camara de visión ha detectado un objeto, y no me gustaría bloquear el programa y por defecto, la camara deja de ver.

Realmente el codigo sería tal que así.

```
import time

## CODIGO A EJECUTAR

while(1):

    #codigo donde la camara esta buscando el tipo de objeto#

    if detecta_objeto_A:
     
        #empezar a temporizar 5 segundos, dependiendo de detecta_objeto_A

        if Temp>=5 and detecta_objeto_A:

          print("Objeto A detectado, durante 5 segundos")
          #codigo a ejecutar

   if detecta_objeto_B:
     
        #empezar a temporizar 5 segundos, dependiendo de detecta_objeto_B
        
        if Temp>=5 amd detecta_objeto_B:
          print("Objeto B detectado durante 5 segundos")
          #codigo a ejecutar

   #codigo a ejecutar#
```

La busqueda es que cuando detecta un objeto, pasen 5 segundos y de esa manera poder verificar que ese objeto es realmente el objeto buscado, y se encuentra ahí durante 5 segundos sin ser una falsa detección. Si en esos 5 segundos el objeto se pierde, para la temporización y no llega a finalizar la temporización.

Por eso lo que digo, que si no han pasado esos 5 segundos, cualquiera de los 2 objetos han sido una falsa detección y no me acaba mostrando los print().

No se si me explico. Gracias!

Comment: Hoy en día, algo así se haría con asyncio, pero depende bastante de si tu software de visión es compatible con las versiones 3.x de python.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

## CODIGO A EJECUTAR

while(1):

    #codigo a ejecutar#

    if condicion_activacion:
     
        #empezar a temporizar 5 segundos

        time.sleep(5)

        print("Han pasado 5 segundos, mostrar mensaje")

        #codigo a ejecutar
```

Con `time.sleep(x)` el programa espera x segundos antes de pasar a la siguiente línea.

Comment: No me vale con time.sleep porque pararía la cámara. He editado el post de arriba con nuevo codigo mejor explicado. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tenemos una función que detecta objetos cada segundo y que tenemos varias *corrutinas* que comprueban si el objeto detectado sigue después de 5 segundos. Se podría resolver así con [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio.html):

```py
import asyncio

ESPERA = 5.0  # espera de 5 segundos

obj_detectado = None


async def vision_objecto():

   while True:
       # CÓDIGO DE VISIÓN: detecta objetos cada 1 segundo
       obj_detectado = ...
       await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def detecta_objeto(obj):

    while True:
        if obj_detectado is obj:
            await asyncio.sleep(ESPERA)
            if obj_detectado is obj:
                print(f"Objecto {obj} detectado")

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        vision_objecto(),
        detecta_objeto(objetoA),
        detecta_objeto(objctoB)
    )


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Contesté más arriba a lo que me pusiste. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No sabría muy bien como integrar eso dentro de la aplicación tendré que probarlo a ver...

Estoy cacharreando con OpenCV para detectar cortornos de objetos entre 2 tipos de objetos de diferentes longitudes. Esas son las condiciones que estoy usando, si uno mide >= 10cm y el otro es <10cm.

A ver como lo integro, supongo que trendré que meter el asyncio.run(main()) para que me lo ejecute cada ciclo while(1) de mi programa.

Una pregunta, ¿los bucles while que usan, salen de ellos con el await.ayncio.sleep(1)  cuando pasan ese segundo no?

¿Como funciona el asyncio.gather?

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Esta pregunta deberías ponerla como comentario o añadida a la pregunta original. Si por _"salir del bucle"_ te refieres a si `ayncio.sleep()` hace algún bloqueo: no, no es bloqueante, el código sigue trabajando y vuelve aquí pasado el tiempo fijado. El `asyncio.gather()` lanza los _awaitables_ como tareas. Es como si se ejecutaran simultáneamente, aunque en monohilo. `asyncio` también te da la opción de lanzar cada tarea en su propio hilo, aunque en la práctica GIL sólo te dejará ejecutar un hilo cada vez. OpenCV sí que es bloqueante, nada se ejecuta mientras estás capturando imagen.

Comment: Gracias Chema, a ver cuando tengo algo de tiempo libre y hago una prueba antes de probarlo con el codigo de la camara, para hacer una idea del funcionamiento.

A ver si lo logro, no parece muy dificil, pero ya veo que da lata lograr eso.

Saludos y gracias.